# Cannot import s3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

i am trying to import s3 so i can use the code `conn = `S3.AWSAuthConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)` as used  [here](https://yashh.com/django-image-crop-and-upload-s3)

but i get this error

```
  import s3
  File "C:\Users\abcedfghijk\Envs\myblog\lib\site-packages\s3__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from .s3 import *
  File "C:\Users\abcedfghijk\Envs\myblog\lib\site-packages\s3\s3.py", line 253
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help out.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

`except Exception, e:` is python2 syntax, which means you have installed s3.

`pip3 install s3` says: *UserWarning: This backport is meant only for Python 2.*

The package you're looking for is boto3. Try:

```
$ pip3 install boto3
$ python3
>>> import boto3
>>> s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Python2 syntax. This library seems old (Last released: May 27, 2015) and the blog post is even older (Published Aug 06, 2009). Either try running this with python2 or use [boto](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) (e.g. `boto3.resource('s3')`)